# How to set properties of same name but different types in inherited classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

I may have asked the question wrongly but stick with me here.

I am making a configuration manager that has a couple of rules.. all `Keys` are string, but `Value` can be either `string`, `int`, `double` or `bool` (but shown as 0,1 integers)

I've wrote a class and some generic stuff and also overrode `ToString();` method to get a nice printing pattern AND on the wrapper class I've created an operator override to get the object. Now I'm trying to create a setter for that object but I'm having some serious troubles since the type of the value doesn't match..

```
public class Config()
{
    public List<ConfigEntry> ConfigLines {get;set;}

    public ConfigEntry this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            if(CfgConfig.Any(x => x.GetKey(true) == key))
            {
                return CfgConfig.Where(x => x.GetKey(true) == key).Single();
            }
            if (ProfileConfig.Any(x => x.GetKey(true) == key))
            {
                return ProfileConfig.Where(x => x.GetKey(true) == key).Single();
            }

            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            //??????????????
        }
    }

    public class ConfigEntry()
    {
        public string CommonStuff {get;set);

        public virtual string GetKey(bool tolower = false)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return CommonStuff;
        }

        public class TextValue : ConfigEntry
        {
            public string Key {get;set;}
            public string Value {get;set;}

            public override string ToString()
           {
             return $@"{Key}={Value};";
           }

            public virtual string GetKey(bool tolower = false)
           {
               if (tolower)
                   return Key.ToLower();
              else
                   return Key;
          }
        }

        public class IntValue : ConfigEntry
        {
            public string Key {get;set;}
            public int Value {get;set;}

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $@"{Key}={Value};";
            }

            public virtual string GetKey(bool tolower = false)
            {
                if (tolower)
                    return Key.ToLower();
                else
                    return Key;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now how could I configure that setter of the operator [] for this to actually work as normal, that if I type, lets say `ConfigLines["anintkey"] = 5;` and `ConfigLines["astringkey"] = "Hello";` that both things work.. I suppose that I do need to use the `<T> class` here somewhere, but I haven't used templates that much and I can't figure out a way to pull this off.
I do want to keep the original list as a base class and then work from that, but I have no clue how to pull this one off.

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `ConfigEntry<T>`, but then you will be forced to make `Config<T>` which contains `List<ConfigEntry<T>>`. So that isn't solution.

All you need is just `dynamic`:

```
var conf = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
conf["url"] = "http://example.com";
conf["timeout"] = 30;
// in some other place
string url = conf["url"];
int timeout = conf["timeout"];
```

Comment: I used a dictionary in my older version of the app but I'm going for a more robust solution now.. making values dynamic actually fixed the problem, I just have to check can a setter like this work

Comment: Most robust solution is to create Config class with all options you need. If you don't want to use dynamic you will not achieve such behaviour `conf["url"] = "http://example.com";conf["timeout"] = 30;`

Comment: And this worked exactly as you said it would and it was perfect for my situation. Thank you! :) except I didn't make a dictionary and I left it as objects of multiple inherited classes and simply made the Value property  a dynamic type